# how to verify signature of SP in IdP | Sustainsys | Saml2 | StubIdp

Tags: saml-2.0, signature, stub, idp, sustainsys-saml2

I have successfully integrated Sustainsys.Saml2. great library, thank you!

Right now I can add IDP metadata into any of my local webs(SP) and it logs-in successfully but I want only specific Service providers can access IDP not any other, IDP should through exception for unauthorized SP. How can I configure this?  Is there any way to Verify the signature/certificate.

Thank you in advance.